# Rule of thumb for calculating cosine similarity on large vectors

Tags: python, scipy

I have a matrix of music listening data where rows are unique musical artists and ~90,000 columns (onne per user in the dataset) where each value is the normalized number of times a given user has listened to a given artist (i.e. the number of times the user has listened to the artist divided by by that user's total number of listens).

I'm using this data to calculate cosine similarity between pairs of artists. Basically, to calculate the similarity between two artists, you just determine the cosine similarity between the two corresponding rows in the matrix (which are essentially vectors where each feature is how much each individual user in the data has listened to the artist). That part's fairly straightforward, but here's my question:

Is there are any rule of thumb for (or even better, a principled way of) determining the minimum number of non-zero dimensions you need to calculate a meaningful similarity with this approach? As an extreme case, suppose we have some user who is the sole listener to two very obscure artists. The method I've described here would result in these two artist having similarity of 1.0, even though common sense tells us that these two artists are not (necessarily) similar at all.

My idea at this point is to set some minimum threshold, either on the overall popularity (i.e. total listens across all users) and artist has, or else on the number of unique users who have listened to an artist. But just picking an arbitrary threshold is, well, arbitrary. Any ideas from those who have faced similar issues?

Comment: The field of science is called Machine Learning. If I understand you right, you want to do Clustering (e.g., http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering) or a dimensionality reduction (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#decomposing-signals-in-components-matrix-factorization-problems)